# How can I clean my these spots on my aluminium moka pot?

Tags: moka, equipment, cleaning

I left my aluminium moka pot unused for a year and it turn out to be so rusty. I think it was too damp at my outer kitchen. Is there a way to revive it?

[image]

Comment: Hi @จ่าง ชาวท่าแซะ, welcome to Coffee SE! For clarification, can you please let us know if this pot is made of aluminum or steel?

Comment: it’s aluminum.  It’s bialetti  brikka pot.

Answer (score 3):

That looks very much like aluminum oxide, caused by exposure of aluminum to oxygen in the air. Don't worry. However unsightly it looks, it's not dangerous. You should be able to remove it with white vinegar or a solution of vinegar in water. Wet a soft cloth or soft-bristled brush with it and gently scrub.